# Can I use ssh to login another host and automatically "su" to another user?

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, authentication, su

E.g, each time I have start from my mac:

`ssh myself@192.168.100.101` to a linux server server and `su oracle`, and type my password. I wish to accelerate this routine by using some alias, which do the ssh login and `su` user at the same time.

I know ssh command can do remote command line and quit. But that's not my requirement: I don't wish ssh login/execute/return, I want it to switch user and I start to work.

Any command line option could help on this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ssh -t myself@192.168.100.101 "su oracle"
```

**-t**

> Force pseudo-terminal allocation.  This can be used to execute
>   arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very
>   useful, e.g. when implementing menu services.  Multiple -t options
>   force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty